# Whether jQuery exists in the current page or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to check wether jQuery script has been included to the page? I have one, but I don't think it's elegant.

```
try { $("body") } catch(e) { /* doesn't exist */ }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
if(window.jQuery)
{
    //jquery found 
}
```